# Unable to View Product List in Home page or category page

Tags: php, magento

i am working in magento 
i have added one product and assign it to few categories.
i wanted to see this products in home page and categories page in which i have assigned it.

i have following code in list.phtml

```
<?php $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection() ?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('No Products Found in this Category') ?></p>
<?php endif: ?>
```

but this always shows **No Products Found in this Category**

Comment: what you have get if you print $_productCollection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to answer this, more information is needed.

Can you please do the following.

Make sure the products you added are :

1. Enabled
2. Set to "catalog,search"
3. Set as "taxable goods"
4. Are set to a positive stock value
5. Are set as "In stock"

once you have doubled checked all of this, please go to the product url. What i mean is, open up the product, find its "URL Key" value and then navigate to your project url with that product key. ie :

www.yourproject/testproducturlkey.html

or

www.yourproject/index.php/testproducturlkey.html

depending on how you have set your project up. you could also type in the product sku value in the search bar and try and find the product like that. if you are able to view this product then we are ready to debug further. can you confirm you are able to see this product being rendered on the frontend correctly?